# Can i do the summation by only one single expression in calculator? How?

Tags: calculator

[image: How to calculate the expression by calculator easily? Help asap]

How to calculate the expression easily?

Comment: It depends on the calculator you have.

Comment: I have CASIO-991ES PLUS

Comment: I'm not familiar with this type of calculator, but at a quick look at an on-line manual for it, I did not see that it had nice built in features for this sort of calculation (although I may have missed something).  Some calculators have built-ins that would make this sort of calculation easily.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your calculator.

The simplest form I found for your numbers is $$1+(p (11 p (p (13 p (14 p-75)+2100)-2275)+13650)-3003) p^{10}$$ or, if you prefer $$1+p^{10} \Big(2002 p^5-10725 p^4+23100 p^3-25025 p^2+13650 p-3003\Big)$$